# Some device doesn't show toolbar back arrow + search view icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, searchview, android-design-library

I am stuck with a silly problem. I have created one activity as below:

[image]

You can see here back arrow and that search icon (below of toolbar)

Now some device is not displaying that as below:

[image]

Here is the XML code of this activity.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activity.ProductMasterListActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:queryHint="@string/string_type_here_to_search"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Can anyone help? Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: is this happening in different devices from specific manufacturer or same device model?

Comment: It's happening with Samsung J7 only. Its working fine for Emulator, Real Me, and Samsung J8.

Comment: attach layout bounds photo from device.

Comment: have you used this both `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: If possible, please attach data or photo from Layout Inspector.